# Converting hex and storing into byte

Tags: c++

I want to convert a decimal value stored in a string into a hex value and store it in a byte variable. How can I do that?

eg

```
std::string DispalyAddress = params.substr(0,2);
```

The result is `12`.

Now I want to convert `12` into hex ie C and store it in a byte variable. Something like

```
byte MyAddress = (byte)DispalyAddress.c_str();
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) I/O manipulator.

Comment: What's a byte variable?

Comment: I have edited the question. I want a hex value in byte variable

Comment: @user2837961 You might need to [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20024742)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you `byte` type is (I assume it's `char` or `unsigned char`), and if I correctly understood your question:

If you can use C++11, then do

```
byte MyAddress = (byte)std::stoi(DisplayAddress, 0, 16);
```

if not, then

```
byte MyAddress = (byte)strtol(DisplayAddress.c_str(), NULL, 16);
```

This will store value 18 (0x12) in `MyAddress`.