# Does a pointer to std::byte have the same aliasing relaxations as char*?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, std-byte

C++ (and C) strict aliasing rules include that a `char*` and `unsigned char*` may alias any other pointer.

AFAIK there is no analogous rule for `uint8_t*`.

Thus my question: What are the aliasing rules for a [`std::byte`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) pointer?

The C++ reference currently just [specifies](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte):

> Like the character types (char, unsigned char, signed char) it can be used to access raw memory occupied by other objects (object representation), but unlike those types, it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing The same aliasing rules apply to `std::byte` as to `char`

Comment: @Justin: You might want to be a little more clear, since "the rules apply" doesn't say which rules apply. `std::byte` has the same rules as `char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Justin: Not when you first posted (you had: "en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/… The aliasing rules apply to `std::byte`"). You've since edited; I loaded it pre-edit. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: See [A byte type: std::byte vs std::uint8_t vs unsigned char vs char vs std::bitset<8>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77097673/5740428)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the current Standard draft ([[basic.types.general]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general)):

> For any object (other than a potentially-overlapping subobject) of trivially copyable type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`, the underlying bytes ([[intro.memory]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.memory)) making up the object can be copied into an array of `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte` ([[cstddef.syn]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstddef.syn)).
> If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.

So yes, the same aliasing rules apply for the three types, just as cppreference sums up.

It also might be valuable to mention ([[basic.lval]/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types the behavior is undefined: <sup>[44](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#footnote-44)</sup>
>
> - [...]
> - a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte` type.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[44](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#footnote-44)</sup> The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object can or cannot be aliased.