# Standard compliant way of swapping bits of two objects in different types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Consider the following two functions:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
void swap1(T* t, S* s)
{
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(S));
  char tmp[sizeof(T)];
  std::memcpy(tmp, t, sizeof(T));
  std::memcpy(t,  s, sizeof(T));
  std::memcpy(s, tmp, sizeof(T));
}
```

and

```
template<typename T, typename S>
void swap2(T* t, S* s)
{
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(S));
  char *tc = (char*)t, *sc = (char*)s;
  std::swap_ranges(tc, tc + sizeof(T), sc);
}
```

Which of them violates the strict aliasing rule? Do both of them violate the rule? If both, how to achieve the goal without violation?

All I can see from C++ standard is that, we can use pointers of certain types including `char*` to point at an arbitrary object, and **access** its stored value. What does **access** mean? Is it just **read** or **read+write**?

I didn't find an emphatic answer from [What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8).
Discussion on [Hacker News - memcpy certainly violates aliasing rules](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25232158) confused me even more.

But by reading the "memcpy version, compliant to C and C++ specs and efficient" section of [Understanding C/C++ Strict Aliasing](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html), it seems at least `swap2` is perfectly fine.

Comment: You'd need casts for `char *tc = t, *sc = s;`.

Comment: `memcpy` doesn't cast between pointers, strict aliasing doesn't apply. It's a typical way of getting around it. `char*` can alias any object, it is also exempt from strict aliasing.  Both look fine to me. I'd expect `memcpy` to be the easiest for the compiler to optimize. Consider using `std::bit_cast` instead, which does the same thing but more clearly communicates the intention.

Comment: Not sure if it's a dupe but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551805/10871073) cites the Standard in saying that data in a `char` array can be copied from **and back to** another data type.

Comment: see [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use `std::bit_cast` from `<bit>`. It also checks for triviality of source and destination, so if either one has certain constructors, a bug is not introduced into your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither implementation violates *the strict aliasing rule*. The rule prohibits reading or writing `T*` via `U*` unless `U*` is `char*`/`unsigned char*`/`std::byte*`. Reading and writing through `char*` is perfectly standard C++.

Whether the object ends up having some value in the end is a whole another story. I don't think standard guarantees anything unless `T` and `U` are the same type. Maybe barring some arithmetic conversions. But I'm not sure.

If you only have a single trivially copyable type `T`, [[basic.types]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-2) says (omitting some details):

> For any object ... of trivially copyable type `T` ... the underlying bytes ... making up the object can be copied into an array of `char` ...
> If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.

Comment: Note the "copied back into the object", that must be an object of which the lifetime has already begun. Copying to a memory that's just a T* will not result in a valid object there. That's whre the bit_cast comment comes into play

Comment: @yeputons I'd seen it but what's the point of saying "If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value". Isn't this obvious? If the standard did not make this statement, what could go wrong?

Comment: By saying "Whether the object ends up having some value in the end is a whole another story", are you suggesting that, even my function does not violate any rule, it could still fail to achieve what it is supposed to achieve?

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/cstring.syn#3 says that `memcpy` implicitly creates an object at the destination. As long as the bytes result in a valid representation for that type of object, then it is fine, otherwise it would never be possible to use `memcpy` to initialize a new object. I can't find anything for `swap_ranges`. But it probably falls under the char pointer indicating provided storage.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I don't think clang and gcc have ever consistently recognized implicit object creation.  If they recognize that a sequence of actions will leave some storage holding a bit pattern that matches a T1 it has previously contained, even if those actions involved copying a T2 that had that bit pattern, they will sometimes fail to recognize that such actions may have modified the storage associated with a T2.

Comment: @user2961927 Nothing is ever "obvious" in formal texts, and especially not in C++. 20 years ago [it was obvious to everyone that dereferencing `nullptr` crashes the application instead of introducing security vulnerabilty](https://thephd.dev/c-undefined-behavior-and-the-sledgehammer-guideline), but it was never codified, so it's not true anymore. In particular, all code is not a valid C++ unless proven otherwise. And then it depends on what exactly `T` and `U` are, I'm not 100% sure what happens here. I think your best bet is to investigate `std::bit_cast` and wording around it.

Comment: @supercat Sounds a lot like you are describing the strict aliasing rule, which do not apply here and is distinct from implicit object creation caused by `memcpy`. If you are describing something else, please clarify the distinction as I didn't notice one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The object creation rules, as applied to PODS, are intended to facilitate essentially the same optimizations, and have many of the same problematic corner cases, as the "strict aliasing rule".  If there were no desire to perform such optimizations, one could simply say that every region of storage which doesn't contain a non-trivial object simultaneously contains all possible trivial objects that would fit, changing the value of any object would change the underlying storage, and changing the underlying storage would simultaneously change the value of all objects therein.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Such an abstraction model would be consistent with all behaviors defined by the C++ Standard, and would be free of many problematic corner cases such as whether a construct like `someUnion.array[x].z =23;` sets the "Active Member" of `someUnion` [since members of trivial-type unions would always be active].  Recognizing that objects may not always be accessible as every type, even if they *exist*, would facilitate many of the optimizations the other rules were intended to facilitate, while offering much greater clarity about what programmers and compilers can do.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Besides, in the cases where I'm saying clang and gcc fail to recognize implicit object creation, every object would be accessed exclusively using lvalues of its type if object creation were properly recognized.  The SAR only poses problems because storage which has been written as a T1 after having previously been used as a T2 isn't always recognized as holding an object of type T1 which should be readable using a `T1*`.