# what does the byte datatype function return in C

Tags: c

May I ask in C what does the following byte mean here?
I thought it should be something like float foo(void), what does the byte mean? 
Does it mean if the required number is 100 in percent, it will return 1111 1111?I am confused with the byte here.

```
    byte foo(void):
    //return required number in percent
```

Comment: The answer depends on what the code defines or typedefs `byte` to mean.  It is likely to be `typedef unsigned char byte;` or something equivalent to that, but that is not certain.  Most likely, the comment means that it will contain a value between 0 and 100, but again, different interpretations are possible and it depends on what the code in the function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context the function is prototyped to return a type called `byte`.  Because [C does not have a native type `byte`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024742/645128), it must be a `typedef`, for example:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

The likely reason for this type is in the comment:

```
//return required number in percent
```

where because the function will return a integer value somewhere is the range of `0` to `100`, 8 bits is more than sufficient.  (in hex: `0x0` to `0x64`, so if 100 is indeed the maximum needed value for the application the MSB will never be used.)
If however the full range of 8 bits is desired then return value could be up to 255.

Comment: So if the number is returned in percent, I can get from 0000 0000 to 0100 0100?

Comment: That's my best guess, the comment being the clue.  However with  8 bits of range and resolutiion the value could be more than 100, but at only at  1% increments. (That's the nature of a char type.) The maximum range would of course be up to 256% assuming 'byte' is a typedef of unsigned char. (1111 1111) Or  0XFF.

Comment: Correction maximum would be 255

Answer (score 0):

```
 typedef unsigned char byte;
```

or

```
 typedef uint8_t byte;
```

Does it explain what the byte is?

Then to display the progress bar you do not need too much precision. So the integer 0 to 100 is good enough and it fits in one byte.

Comment: No,it doesn't explain.

Comment: @ZhiqiangYang You are the one that can explain what `byte` is. It's your code, please show us the type definition of it.

Comment: The code I posted is from the other head file which I am not supposed to add or delete anything in it.